# 500 internal server error wordpress with godaddy

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am getting the following type of error message on both admin and frontend of my WordPress website.

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
> administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything
> you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.

I already tried to rename the plugin directory, removed or renamed the `.htaccess` file and changed WordPress file permissions to 755. But no luck.

Comment: This question is really general, you should look at the error.log to see what's the matter.
Alost set php.ini setting `error_reporting` to E_ALL

Comment: How can i change the php.ini file make it clear please

Comment: Is your IP correct?  Is it possible that you have made a mistake in the hosting side when you added the domain (typo or anything like that)?

Comment: no typo errors..url is same in my server

Comment: Well, on a normal server you just edit the php.ini file under `/etc/php/apache2/php.ini` or similar, on godaddy the file might be somewhere in your FTP directory tree(probably root folder), or you can do it through their control panel.

Comment: As the error says `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

Answer (score 1):

I have the exactly same problem on my WP site, because I reached the limit of my godaddy web hosting resources. They say I need to buy more server resources for my website to work regularly.